# Postgres select object where running total (sum) of columns exceeds a number inside of a group_by

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Fairly complex query I have been trying to solve and cannot quite get.  I will layout the architecture then get into the problem.  Students play game rounds and inside, they commit 'attempts' at a problem.  Each attempt will carry a weight depending on if they got it correct, and how fast they got it. The goal of the query is to generate ProblemMastery objects based off this historical data

```
ATTEMPT
 id | problem_id | weight | game_round_id | ended_at
----|------------|--------|---------------|-----------
 1  |     4      |   3    |       1       | 4/11/2018

PROBLEM
 id |..irrelevant math fact information
----|------------|-----------
 1  |

GAMEROUND
 id | student_id | ended_at
----|------------|-----------
 1  |     1      | 4/11/2018

PROBLEM MASTERY
 id | student_id | student_id | date_mastered
----|------------|------------|--------------
 1  |     1      |     1      |   4/11/2018
```

When a student completes an attempt in a GameRound, the attempt will carry a weight of 0-4 depending on how fast the problem inside the attempt was solved during gameplay.  If a student gets sum(weight) += 7 in consideration of all their attempts for a certain problem, they get a ProblemMastery object assigned to them, linking them to the problem, and adding a date_mastered time stamp.

This architecture has been modified recently and the old ProblemMasteries need to be deleted as they are inaccurate, we need to regenerate all the ProblemMasteries based off of old GameRound and attempt data

For each problem through a students attempts, we need to select the attempt that put the running weight total >=7.  That way we know what date the problem was mastered on.  If a student has 4 attempts at a problem, the first one with weight = 2, second with weight = 2, third with weight = 4, and fourth with weight = 4, the problem_id should should be returned with the date that it was mastered.  So an example might look like this {[problem__1_id]: "1-12-2018",[problem__2_id]: "1-14-2018"..etc}

I have a sneaking suspicion that this can be done in one query with GROUP and OVER, but im not sure how.

**EDIT**
The answer as provided by @AlexanderMP was so close.  I accepted it and modified the answer that works on my system.  For the record this is embedded in a rails platform

```
game_round_ids_array = "("+student.game_rounds.pluck(:id).join(", ")+")"
      query_data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('
        WITH progress AS (
            SELECT
              sum(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY problem_id ORDER BY ended_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_sum,
              problem_id,
              game_round_id,
              ended_at
            FROM attempts
            WHERE game_round_id in '+game_round_ids_array+'
          )
          SELECT DISTINCT ON (problem_id)
            problem_id,
            game_round_id,
            ended_at
          FROM progress
          WHERE running_sum > 6
          ORDER BY problem_id, ended_at
      ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get progress per problem using this query, that uses a CTE for the window functions, and then a filter for the result of that window function (which can't be applied in a filter directly, as it's executed AFTER the filter):

```
WITH progress AS (
  SELECT
    sum(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY problem_id ORDER BY ended_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_sum,
    problem_id,
    ended_at
  FROM attempt
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (problem_id)
  problem_id,
  ended_at AS date_mastered
WHERE running_sum > threshold
ORDER BY problem_id, ended_at
```

You can use the results to join with your other data and get what you need, since it's not entirely clear how data correlates, but it appears that you can determine the `student_id` from the `problem_id`

Comment: Thanks for the query, reading through it it actually makes a lot of sense.  I modified the question as I put too many columns in Problem.  I was incorrect about that table structure, apologies for that.  Its more like a Student has many GameRound, which each have many Attempts, which each have 1 problem.  and a ProblemMastery has 1 student and 1 problem.  I am tinkering with your query now to try and get something going

Comment: I got the answer! It was based off of your resolution! Posting it in the edits for the question